# Attribute 'data' sometimes breaks on rendering

Tags: json, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a server side object.

```
public class OptionRelation
{
    public intOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Child { get; set; }
    public string Peer { get; set; }
}
```

Inside of my view, I do the following:

```
//where relations is a List<OptionRelation>
var a = relations.FindAll(r => r.OptionId == option.OptionID);
string data_relation = "";
if(a.Count > 0)
{
    data_relation = "data-relation=" + Json.Encode(a);
}

<input type="checkbox" @data_relation />
```

Attribute @data gets populated the way I expect most of the time.  However, sometimes it breaks.  If I open it in FireBug, the attributes of the `<input>` are all garbage.  The only thing I can think of is that when it breaks the length of data-relation is slightly longer then the rest of the cases.  Particularly, it breaks when data-relation should be:

```
data-relation="[{"OptionId":80,"Type":"required_1","Child":"#1625, #1626, #1627","Peer":""}]"
```

Any ideas why this is breaking?

SOLUTION:  I ended up rewriting tons of code and finally getting it to work using custom HTML helper and partially utilizing Darin's code for HTML helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Html.Raw` in the attribute to avoid Razor performing double HTML encoding, just like this:

```
var a = relations.FindAll(r => r.OptionId == option.OptionID);
string data_relation = "";
if(a.Count > 0)
{
    data_relation = string.Format(
        "data-relation=\"{0}\"", 
        Html.AttributeEncode(Json.Encode(a))
    );
}

<input type="checkbox" @Html.Raw(data_relation) />
```

This being said, writing so much C# code in a view is probably one of the worst things you could do in an ASP.NET MVC application. It's a horrible to look and maintain. That's not what views are supposed to do. That's what custom HTML helpers might be useful. So why spaghettifying your views when you can simply write the following

```
@Html.MyCheckBox(option.OptionID)
```

That kind of looks better compared to the previous abomination, doesn't it?

And here's what I mean by the custom helper:

```
public static class CheckBoxExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyCheckBox(
        this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<OptionRelation>> htmlHelper, 
        int optionId
    )
    {
        var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
        var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
        var a = model.Where(x => x.OptionId == optionId);
        if (a.Count() > 0)
        {
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(a);
            checkbox.Attributes["data-relation"] = json;
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(checkbox.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

Comment: Html.AttributeEncode line is throwing null reference exception.

Comment: I actually do have it in @helper in App_Code folder, just didn't mention it.  But thanks for pointing out!

Comment: This line is still crashing:  Html.AttributeEncode(Json.Encode(a))  object is null

Comment: I rewrote a lot of code and got it to work using custom HTML helper.  The first code snippet in your answer throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.  Something about Html.Raw and Html.AttributeEncode not liking Json encoded strings and empty strings.  Maybe you should take it out of the answer?